# Unable to attain correct results with CASE WHEN statement in Databricks with Left Join

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to do a left join between two datasets using a CASE WHEN in databricks statement with the following code:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
 (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts_primarysecondaryfocus)RowNum FROM dataverse.accountv41
 ),CTE2 AS
 (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts_primarysecondaryfocus)RowNum FROM dataverse.optionsetmetadatav3
 )
 SELECT C1.SinkCreatedOn,C1.SinkModifiedOn,C1.statecode,C1.statuscode
       ,CASE WHEN C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus <> IFNULL(C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus,'') THEN C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus ELSE C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus END AS ts_primarysecondaryfocus
 FROM CTE1 C1 LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.RowNum = C2.RowNum
```

The expected output should be:
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| SinkCreatedOn   | SinkModifiedOn  | statecode | statuscode | ts_primarysecondaryfocus |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:25 | 5/19/2022 16:25 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:25 | 5/19/2022 16:25 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          | donald                   |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          | TBC                      |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          | Tier 1                   |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          | Tier 2                   |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+

However, I'm getting the following output

+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| SinkCreatedOn   | SinkModifiedOn  | statecode | statuscode | ts_primarysecondaryfocus |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:25 | 5/19/2022 16:25 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:25 | 5/19/2022 16:25 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+

Sample Data
accountv41

+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| SinkCreatedOn   | SinkModifiedOn  | statecode | statuscode | ts_primarysecondaryfocus |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:25 | 5/19/2022 16:25 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:15 | 5/19/2022 16:15 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:19 | 5/19/2022 16:19 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5/19/2022 16:15 | 5/19/2022 16:15 | 0         | 1          |                          |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+

Sample Data
optionsetmetadatav3

+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| participationtypemask | instancetypecode | donotpostalmail | donotfax     | ts_primarysecondaryfocus |
+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| Sender                | Not Recurring    | Allow           | Allow        | Tier 1                   |
+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| To Recipient          | Not Recurring    | Allow           | Allow        | Tier 2                   |
+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| CC Recipient          | Not Recurring    | Allow           | Allow        | TBC                      |
+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| BCC Recipient         | Recurring Master | Do Not Allow    | Do Not Allow | donald                   |
+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| Required attendee     | Recurring Master | Do Not Allow    | Do Not Allow |                          |
+-----------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------+

Any thoughts on why the Left Join won't work?

Comment: I may resubmit this question as I'm stuggiing to create a table with Markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the misinterpretation of the table values. When I tried reproducing this query, it gave the correct output when empty values in `ts_primarysecondaryfocus` column in both tables are empty string `''`. It fails when these values are `null` instead.

**When the empty values of `ts_primarysecondaryfocus` are `''`:**

- `accountv41` table data:

[image]

- `optionsetmetadatav3` table data:

[image]

- Query output (the query you used):

[image]

**When the empty values of `ts_primarysecondaryfocus` are `null`:**

- `accountv41` table data:

[image]

- `optionsetmetadatav3` table data:

[image]

- Query output (Your Query):

[image]

- Modified query output:

[image]

I modified the `CASE` condition so that it would work irrespective of the empty values (empty string or null) present in `ts_primarysecondaryfocus`. The following query should work without any issue.

```
WITH CTE1 AS
 (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts_primarysecondaryfocus)RowNum FROM accountv41
 ),CTE2 AS
 (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ts_primarysecondaryfocus)RowNum FROM optionsetmetadatav3
 )
 SELECT C1.SinkCreatedOn,C1.SinkModifiedOn,C1.statecode,C1.statuscode
       ,CASE WHEN IFNULL(C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus,'') <> IFNULL(C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus,'') THEN C2.ts_primarysecondaryfocus ELSE C1.ts_primarysecondaryfocus END AS ts_primarysecondaryfocus
 FROM CTE1 C1 LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.RowNum = C2.RowNum
```

Comment: OMG! This is truly amazing.  I won’t lie I haven’t thoroughly tested this yet, but looking at the screenshots you have provided it clearly looks like you have resolved the issue. It’s very late at the moment so I will test this in the morning In the meantime , I can’t thank you enough. This resolution has literally kept me in a job. Thanks Saideep